# Google+ sharing post on specific friend's stream in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, google-plus

Is there any url or technique available in google+ in order to share posts on the one specific friend's stream?

I found this url: https://plus.google.com/share?url={your url}
but the problem with this url is that we can't pass the friends id or name of the friend in parameter of the url in order to get the prefilled friends name written on that field (where we mention with whom we want to share the post) when the link is opened in the browser.

When I am using the above found url, I have to select the name of the friend manually on the browser after the link has been opened. I want to prefil that field in which we write the name of the friend with whom we want to share.

Can any one please help me out. It is one of my requirement. I am developing application in xcode

Answer (score 1):

Google+ does not allow for programmatic writing to anyone's stream. Users in Google+ always retain control over what to share and who to share it to. You can use the [Google+ SDK for iOS to **prompt** users to share](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share), but they have ultimate control to choose who to share to.

Comment: I know that google+ does not allow for programmatic writing, my requirement is whenever the user is about to open the url of the share feature on the browser then before opening the url the user can pass the name of the friend in url parameter, so that whenever the link is opened the name of the friend should be prefilled and the only thing will be left for the user is to click the "Share Button" when the link is opened on the browser. So tell me is that possible?

Comment: You can prefill users for sharing of interactive posts, which requires using Google+ Sign-In, but that is slightly different in usage than what you're asking about.

Comment: I want to prefill the receivers name, like I want to share a post with you so is there any parameter in google+ share url in which i can pass your id or name so that when that url opens in the browser your name should be written on the receivers list, and only wat I have to do is to press the share button over there. So is that possible?

Comment: Can't do it with a URL and not with a normal share.

Comment: please answer my this question also   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16211986/google-chat-window-on-google-mobile-website

Answer (score 1):

For native iOS there is no way to prefill the recipients. You can on Android and via the Javascript share rendering on the web, but not using the iOS SDK. It's definitely worth requesting the feature on the issue tracker if it's something you're interested in though! https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/list

Comment: please answer my this question as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16237581/linkedin-not-showing-senders-name